# Getting options into a Perl program

Tags: perl, command-line, arguments

I've been googling for some time now and strangely didn't find anything that answers my question.

I want to pass -n as an option to the program, where n is an integer.

This is what I have:

```
if($ARGV[0] eq "-A_NUMBER")
```

Is there some type of wildcard I can use for this? So the condition is true for any minus sign followed by any integer (or character)?

Comment: Thanks! This works! Does the ^ indicate start of line anchor? How does this work?

Comment: it's a regular expression, which matches - followed by a single digit at the start of $ARGV[0]. so it'll match -1, -2, -29, -2orthree but not -two or -three. Try looking up perl regular expressions

Comment: great, i've changed this to answer my own question. thanks

Comment: @TomTanner: `-\d` won't match -29 ;)

Comment: @mpe : The regex will match. `-29` contains a `-` followed by a digit (`\d`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd reccomend having a read about [Getopt::Std](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) it is more long winded than just inspecting @ARGV, but more robust

Comment: ... or have a look at [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html). But don't reinvent the wheel and make use of CPAN and use welltested and optimized modules.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if ($ARGV[0] =~ /^-\d/)
```

This regular expression matches a minus sign then a number.

"^" anchors the match to the start of the line and "\d" is an escape character that represents a number